# Allow user to run specific commands

Tags: command-line, permissions, 22.04, sudo

How do I enable a user to run specific sudo commands without the need to type a password?

I already tried the following:

I have a script `/usr/local/bin/perform-update` with the rights `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
sudo snap refresh
```

I also have a user `john` that is part of sudoers. He can execute the command by typing `perform-update`, but he will need to type a password. To stop his need for typing his password with this command I tried adding a new line using `sudo visudo`:

```
john    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/perform-update
```

But the user still needs to enter a password when calling the command `perform-update`. So I added all the necessary apt and snap commands using `sudo visudo`:

```
john    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update, /usr/bin/apt -y dist-upgrade, /usr/bin/apt -y autoremove, /usr/bin/snap refresh
```

But the user still needs to enter a password when calling the command `perform-update`.

What do I need to do so that he does not have to enter any password when executing `perform-update`?

**Edit 1:**

Based on the answers of @waltinator and @terdon I updated the following.

`/usr/local/bin/perform-update`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update
sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt -y autoremove
sudo snap refresh
```

`sudo visudo`:

```
john    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/perform-update
john    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update, /usr/bin/apt -y dist-upgrade, /usr/bin/apt -y autoremove, /usr/bin/snap refresh
```

Unfortunately I am still asked for the password when I call `perform-update` as user `john`. Where is the error in `visudo`?

Comment: Either put the `sudo ...` commands in your `perform-update` script; OR add to `~john/.bashrc`: `alias perform-update="sudo $(type -p perform-update)`. You may have to add `perform-update` to your `sudoers` file. Suggestion: Reread `man sudoers`, and combine the allowed commands into a "Command list", makes future `sudoers` management easier.

Comment: Ubuntu systems are designed to avoid the need for such update scripts. Apt's Unattended Upgrades runs twice daily already, and snapd checks for updates four times daily. All in the background, all as root, regardless of who is logged in.

Comment: @waltinator I think you have misread the question. The OP already has the `sudo` commands in their `perform-update` script, they have already added `perform-update` to `sudoers`, and they are already using a "Command list".

Comment: You are using `apt-get` in the script, but have `apt` in `sudoers`. Does it work as expected if you use the same command in both? Either change the script or the sudoers file but make sure they are referring to the same command and let us know if that works (or just post it as an answer, if it does).

Comment: Thanks your your replies. Unfortunately I am still asked to type the password when calling `perform-update` as user john. I just updated the post and added **Edit 1**.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -l` when running as user `john`? How exactly are you running the `perform-update` script?